# Is this simplistic interest rate used?

Tags: interest-rate, interest

Suppose A is the initial investment, r is the interest rate (r > 0). The target interest rate model is then A(1 + r)^t, where t is the time since the moment at which the interest rate started to compound.

Now, two questions:

1. Is it used anywhere?
2. If yes, does it have a name?

Comment: "Simple" is a word with specific meaning in interest calculations, and does not refer to the model you quote...

Answer (score 3):

This is a formula for **compound interest**, but you need to be careful in defining r, whose correct value depends on how t is measured and how the interest is compounded.

The formula can be used if t is measured in compounding intervals and r is the interest paid in each compounding interval. You can also interpret the formula where each unit of t is *several* compounding intervals and r is the *compounded* yield over that unit of time. Thus, if t is measured in years and the interest is compounded *at least* yearly (could also be quarterly, monthly, etc.), then the formula holds with r being the [annual percentage yield](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/apy.asp) (APY).

Example: Invest A = $100 at an interest *rate* of 24% per year, compounded monthly, for 36 months. (The interest rate is taken to be large so the effects of compounding are noticeable.) If we measure t in months, we take r = **0.02 = 2%** (interest paid per month) and t = **36**, giving A(1 + r)^t = **$204**.

To use the formula instead with a larger unit of time -- years -- we must compute the APY, r = (1 + 0.02)^12 - 1 = **0.268 = 26.8%**. Then with t = **3**, we obtain A(1 + r)^t = **$204**. The answer is the same, as it must be.